# creating HTML dynamically Or Just replace values where ever applicable?

Tags: jquery

I have got a static HTML as shown below given by CSS developer

```
<div class="printHeader">
                <div></div>
              <div class="rest_head">
                    <h1 class="rest_name">Paris Restaurant</h1>
                    <h6 class="rest_adres">Opp. DBAFC Banck, FRIIUU, RAtech city, MAHERR - 500 081.<br> Phone: 9001 1156782</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now my requirement is that i need to append dynamic values where ever applicable .

My question is should i create a HTML dynamically

**First Approach**

For example

Create the following div dynamically

```
    <div></div>
              <div class="rest_head">
                    <h1 class="rest_name">Paris Restaurant</h1>
                    <h6 class="rest_adres">Opp. DBAFC Banck, FRIIUU, RAtech city, MAHERR - 500 081.<br> Phone: 9001 1156782</h6>
                </div>

and append it to printHeader
```

OR

**Second Approach**

```
Or should i just replace the values where ever applicable ??

What would be faster (Mine is a mobile application )
```

The HTML i have shown here is smaller it is much more bigger .
please share your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will suggest you to follow your second approach

because it is more customization friendly

you can use some placeholder for dynamic values like ##Address##  or @@Address@@ and just replace those values in your code it have two benefits

1. if you change your HTML design then you not need to worry about your code it will work fine,
2. it will be easy to separate your code and design as well i have same situation in web application for email template and used first approach and after some time it will be headache for me every time UI changed than i need to change my code accordingly

so i suggest for second approach