# jquery performance, javascript

Tags: jquery

I just want to know which is better way of appending data.

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="d1"></div>
   <div id="d2"></div>
   <div id="d3"></div>
   <div id="d4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

case 1:

in javascript: getting response by ajax

```
$("#d1").append(response.data1);
$("#d2").append(response.data2);
$("#d3").append(response.data3);
$("#d4").append(response.data4);
```

case 2:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="d"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in javascript file :

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    $("d").append("<div>" + response.data1 + "</div><div>" + response.data2 + "</div><div>" + response.data3 + "</div><div>" + response.data4 + "</div>");
}
```

Which case is better and preferred?

Comment: IMHO , case 1 : is better , as building HTML is costlier than appending data . however both are okay .

Comment: this may help you  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919540/creating-html-dynamically-or-just-replace-values-where-ever-applicable

Comment: Second way is better because you ruining trough DOM only once to select DIV. Its faster than ruining trough DOM multiple times. Anyway hwlo structure for me looks a little strange, i prefer `<html><body><div =class="responses"></div></body></html>` than with jquery `var target=$('.responses'); $.each(response, function(i,c){ target.append('<div id="re'+i+'">'+v+'</div>')});`

Comment: @PreethiJain exactly the opposite is true. It's much quicker to build a string and append once. DOM operations are an order of magnitude slower than concatenating a string (although still fast enough that the difference is almost imperceptible unless dealing with masses of data)

Comment: @OP the second method follows better practices (ie. DRY) and would be faster - although you're missing the `#` in the selector and the `for` loop seems redundant

Comment: note that in case 1, each data would not get a div as you have illustrated in case 2. Also you could use the html() method in case 2

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan,  Thanks for correcting me  :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Thanks for your input . could you say more about that redundant loop thing you pointed..

Comment: @Walberg I mean that you iterate the `i` variable, but never use it in the loop